# Convergence rate of tail probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I have $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_n\to0$ a.s. ($X$ and $Y_n$ may be dependent). For $t>0$, when does
$$\frac{P(X+Y_n/n>nt)}{P(X>nt)} \to 1$$ 
as $n\to\infty$. Maybe you have some hints or references?

Comment: maybe try to show $ P\{X+Y_n /n  \leq nt | X> nt \} \rightarrow 0$